# Remove virtual directory/web application under Default Web Site using .NET

Tags: .net, iis, wix

I'm working on an uninstaller that has to check if a webapplication/virtual directory is present in IIS and remove it if it's there. Right now I'm using VBScript to check if virtual directory exists,

```
Function VDirExists( name )
Dim objIIS
If IsEmpty(name) Or IsNull(name) Or Len(name) = 0 Then
    VDirExists = False      
    Exit Function
End If

On Error Resume Next
Set objIIS = GetObject( "IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root/" & name )

If Err.Number = 0 Then    
    VDirExists = True
Else        
    Err.Clear
    VDirExists = False
End If
'MsgBox " VDIR Exists IIS: " & VDirExists & "Name :" & name
End Function
```

For deleting the virtual directory, I'm using the following code,

```
set objW3SVC = getObject("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root")    
objVirtualDir = objW3SVC.Delete("IISWebVirtualDir", "AppName")
```

The problem is this seems to be outdated and doesn't work in windows servers/machines where IIS 6 Management Compatibility windows feature is not enabled.  Is there a way to achieve this using C# or WIX. Is there a .NET code that will work for all versions or IIS or windows servers?

Comment: I don't know, but [did you try PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadminstration/remove-website)?

Comment: wanted to achieve this using .NET. Will try PowerShell see

Comment: Just for the record: PowerShell depends on the .NET framework. Whatever it does should be doable in C# as well I would presume?